# foreign key constraints on table with compound primary key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables :

first one is something like that :

```
Person
       first_name (primary key)
       family_name (primary key)
       age
       [other things..]
```

second one is :

```
Doctor
       first_name
       family_name
       specialty
```

So basically, in the table Person, their can't be 2 Person with the same `first_name` and `family_name`. This works well if I both set them on `primary key` using phpmyadmin.

My problem is that now I want to make it impossible to add a `Doctor` who is not a `Person`. I've tried putting a foreign key constraint on `doctor.first_name` and `doctor.family_name`, but it obviously doesn't fix my issue.

(Don't ask me to use an id or something, my tables are much more complicated than that and I can't use an id, it has to be a table with composite primary key).

Comment: Well, even if you state not to ask you to use an ID, every sensible programmer would **ask you to use an ID**. If you'd use an ID in every table, this problem (and a lot more to come) would be so very easy to solve... Example: what will you do when someone changes his name? When two people have the same name?

Comment: That is not the real reason for adding a surrogate key. The real reason is that the primary key is likely to be referenced (as foreign key) by some other table. And then a name change will become cumbersome.

Comment: This is part of a school project and I can't do everything I want. If you had to not use and ID and stick to the first_name/family_name, what would you do ?

Comment: I mean that if a Doctor is named "John Smith" then it also has to be a Person named "John Smith".

Comment: Yes, I read it more carefully and it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wording is not accurate. A table cannot have 2 Primary Keys. It can have, however, a **compound** (composite) **Primary Key**, that is made of 2 or more columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(      first_name 
,      family_name 
,      age
,      ...
,   PRIMARY KEY (first_name, family_name)
)
```

Leaving aside discussions about surrogate vs. natural keys, when you have such a compound Primary Key, any Foreign Key from another table should be a compound one and reference your compound Primary Key:

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor
(      first_name
,      family_name
,      specialty
,      ...
,   PRIMARY KEY (first_name, family_name)

,   FOREIGN KEY (first_name, family_name)
      REFERENCES Person (first_name, family_name)
)
```

This kind of foreign key constraint, where the `PRIMARY KEY` of a table (`Doctor`) is also a `FOREIGN KEY` to another table (`Person`) is the common solution for a `1::0..1` relationship (also called supertype/subtype).

Comment: Thanks, it actually helps, but do you know how to set up a composite foreign key using phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I think there's a Relation View (inside Structure view) in phpmyadmin.

Comment: And you can always use `ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY ...` syntax in SQL view. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html